# Kafka's log directories should only contain Kafka topic data

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes, confluent-platform

I'm trying to run confluent kafka image in kubernetes environment & facing

```
FATAL [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.common.KafkaException: Found directory /var/lib/kafka/data, 'data' is not in the form of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete (if marked for deletion).
Kafka's log directories (and children) should only contain Kafka topic data.
```

My deployment config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-confluent
  labels:
    app: kafka-confluent
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-confluent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-confluent
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zookeeper-kafka
        image: zookeeper:3.5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
      - name: kafka-confluent
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "exec kafka-server-start /etc/kafka/server.properties \
          --override reserved.broker.max.id=2147483647 \
          --override zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 \
          --override listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 \
          "
```

To solve this I've tried to mount some ephemeral volume like this.

```
volumes:
- name: kafka-data
  emptyDir: {}
...
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /var/lib/kafka/data
  name: kafka-data
```

And clear the `data` dir with init container:

```
containers:
- name: cleaner
  image: busybox
  command: ['rm', '-rf', '/var/lib/kafka/data/*']
```

Both tries failed with the same result.

Also If I run the image & list the data `/var/lib/kafka/data/`
Looks like the directory is empty.

```
docker run --rm -it confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0 bash
root@35087653f43a:/# ls /var/lib/kafka/data/ -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Apr 16 09:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:20 ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working configuration:

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/kafka
```

and in the command, override the `log.dirs`

```
kafka-server-start /etc/kafka/server.properties \
    --override log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka
```

Answer (score 3):

is it your error? 
[image]

Fix add this:

```
log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka/data
```

in server.properties

Answer (score 0):

in my windows system I added this

log.dirs=F:\softwares\kafka_2.12-2.5.1\data

server.properties
where

F:\softwares\kafka_2.12-2.5.1
is my kafka directory and issue resolved
here I created data folder inside kafka directory, it was not there when I extracted kafka from 7zip tool.